How to replace frame in FreeSwitch?
I tried to implement end to end encryption to freeswitch, I attempt to decrypt audio payload, after I log my decryption function, it seems that I can decrypt the payload. Now I am confused how to replace my encrypted audio frame with my new decrypted audio frame since the length of encrypted frame and decrypted frame is different. Here is my attempt:
// Function to copy frame trailer //TODO IVAN
// Function to copy frame trailer
void copy_frame_trailer(const uint8_t *actual_frame_data, size_t actual_frame_size, size_t frame_trailer_size, uint8_t *frame_trailer) {
    // Calculate the starting position to copy from
    size_t start_index = (actual_frame_size > frame_trailer_size) ? (actual_frame_size - frame_trailer_size) : 0;

    // Copy data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < frame_trailer_size; ++i) {
        frame_trailer[i] = actual_frame_data[start_index + i];
    }
}

void copy_frame_iv(const uint8_t *actual_frame_data, size_t iv_start, size_t iv_len, uint8_t *iv) {
    // Copy data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < iv_len; ++i) {
        iv[i] = actual_frame_data[iv_start + i];
    }
}

void copy_frame_payload(const uint8_t *actual_frame_data, size_t payload_start, size_t payload_len, uint8_t *payload) {
    // Copy data
    for (size_t i = 0; i < payload_len; ++i) {
        payload[i] = actual_frame_data[payload_start + i];
    }
}

// Function to log bytes
void log_bytes(const uint8_t *bytes, size_t len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "%u ", bytes[i]);
    }
}

// Function to allocate memory
uint8_t* allocate_memory(size_t size) {
    uint8_t *ptr = malloc(size * sizeof(uint8_t));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_ERROR, "Memory allocation failed\n");
    }
    return ptr;
}

int decrypt(const uint8_t* key,
            const uint8_t* payload,
            size_t payload_length,
            const uint8_t* iv,
            const uint8_t* frame_header,
            size_t len_unencrypted_bytes,
            uint8_t* decrypted_payload) {
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;
  int len;
  int plaintext_len;
  int tag_offset = payload_length - 16;
  int rv; // Declare rv here

  // Create and initialize the cipher context
  if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) {
    printf("Error in Decryption 100\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Initialize the decryption operation with the cipher type and mode
  if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
    printf("Error in Decryption 200\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Set key and IV
  if (!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, NULL, NULL, (const unsigned char *)key, iv)) {
    printf("Error in Decryption 300\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Provide frame header as Additional Authenticated Data (AAD)
  if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, NULL, &len, frame_header, len_unencrypted_bytes)) {
    printf("Error in Decryption 400\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Decrypt payload
  if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, decrypted_payload, &len, payload, tag_offset)) {
    printf("Error in Decryption 500\n");
    return -1;
  }

  plaintext_len = len;

  // Set the expected tag value
  if (!EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_TAG, 16, (void *)(payload + tag_offset))) {
    printf("Error in Decryption 600\n");
    return -1;
  }

  // Finalize the decryption
  rv = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, decrypted_payload + len, &len); // Move the declaration of rv here
  if (1 != rv) {
    plaintext_len = -1; // Authentication failed
  }

  // Clean up
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

  return plaintext_len;
}



// Function to decrypt the frame data
void decrypt_frame(switch_frame_t **frame, switch_media_type_t type) {
    if (*frame) {
        const uint8_t encryptionKey[] = {223, 116, 117, 51, 153, 134, 210, 49, 58, 39, 224, 150, 205, 210, 1, 190, 142, 160, 171, 87, 225, 122, 177, 187, 211, 228, 160, 100, 238, 101, 111, 202};
        switch_frame_t *actualFrame = *frame;
        size_t frame_trailer_size = 4;
        uint8_t frame_trailer[frame_trailer_size];
        size_t len_unencrypted_bytes = 0;
        uint8_t *frame_header = NULL;
        size_t iv_len = 0;
        size_t iv_start = 0;
        uint8_t *iv = NULL;
        size_t payload_length = 0;
        size_t payload_start = 0;
        uint8_t *payload = NULL;
        uint8_t decrypted_payload[20000];
        int plaintext_len = 0;
        uint8_t *decrypted_frame = NULL;

        if (type == SWITCH_MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            len_unencrypted_bytes = 1;
        }

        if (type == SWITCH_MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            len_unencrypted_bytes = 10;
        }

        frame_header = allocate_memory(len_unencrypted_bytes);
        if (frame_header == NULL) {
            return; // Memory allocation failed
        }

        // switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "Encrypted total length: %u\n", actualFrame->datalen);

        // Get frame header, frame header contains unencrypted bytes
        memcpy(frame_header, actualFrame->data, len_unencrypted_bytes);
        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "Frame header: ");
        // log_bytes(frame_header, len_unencrypted_bytes);

        // Get 4 bytes of frame trailer, frame trailer contains 2 bytes of IV size and two bytes of IV checksum
        copy_frame_trailer(actualFrame->data, actualFrame->datalen, frame_trailer_size, frame_trailer);
        switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "Frame trailer: ");
        // log_bytes(frame_trailer, frame_trailer_size);

        // Get IV
        iv_len = frame_trailer[0];
        if (iv_len != 12) {
            switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "IV length is not 12 bytes\n");
        } else {
            iv_start = actualFrame->datalen - frame_trailer_size - iv_len;
            iv = allocate_memory(iv_len);
            if (iv == NULL) {
                free(frame_header);
                return; // Memory allocation failed
            }

            copy_frame_iv(actualFrame->data, iv_start, iv_len, iv);
            switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "IV: ");
            // log_bytes(iv, iv_len);

            // Copy encrypted payload
            payload_length = actualFrame->datalen - (len_unencrypted_bytes + iv_len + frame_trailer_size);
            payload = allocate_memory(payload_length);
            payload_start = len_unencrypted_bytes;
            copy_frame_payload(actualFrame->data, payload_start, payload_length, payload);
            switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "Payload length: %zu\n", payload_length);
            // Print first three payload bytes
            // log_bytes(payload, 5);

            // Decrypt the frame data
            plaintext_len = decrypt(encryptionKey, payload, payload_length, iv, frame_header, len_unencrypted_bytes, decrypted_payload);
            switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "Decrypted Payload length: %d\n", plaintext_len);
            // Print first three decrypted payload bytes
            // log_bytes(decrypted_payload, 5);

            // Allocate decrypted_frame based on len_unencrypted_bytes + plaintext_len
            decrypted_frame = allocate_memory(len_unencrypted_bytes + plaintext_len);

            if (decrypted_frame != NULL) {
                // Copy frame_header of unencrypted bytes to decrypted_frame
                memcpy(decrypted_frame, frame_header, len_unencrypted_bytes);

                // Copy decrypted result to frame_data after unecrypted bytes
                memcpy(decrypted_frame + len_unencrypted_bytes, decrypted_payload, plaintext_len);

                // Copy new decrypted frame to frame data
                for (size_t i = 0; i < len_unencrypted_bytes + plaintext_len; ++i) {
                    // Cast void pointers to uint8_t pointers before accessing them
                    ((uint8_t *)actualFrame->data)[i] = ((uint8_t *)decrypted_frame)[i];
                }

                //Delete the rest of frame
                for (size_t i = len_unencrypted_bytes + plaintext_len; i < actualFrame->datalen; ++i) {
                    ((uint8_t *)actualFrame->data)[i] = 128;
                }

                // Update datalen of actualFrame
                // actualFrame->datalen = len_unencrypted_bytes + plaintext_len;
            } else {
                switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_ERROR, "Failed to allocate memory for decrypted frame\n");
            }
        }

        // switch_log_printf(SWITCH_CHANNEL_LOG, SWITCH_LOG_INFO, "=========================\n");

        free(frame_header);
        free(iv);
    }
}



My attempt trying to replace the frame one by one based on new length of my decrypted data like below, then change the len of data inside

switch_frame_t -> datalen

        for (size_t i = len_unencrypted_bytes + plaintext_len; i < actualFrame->datalen; ++i) {
                    ((uint8_t *)actualFrame->data)[i] = 128;
                }

                // Update datalen of actualFrame
                actualFrame->datalen = len_unencrypted_bytes + plaintext_len;

I think this is not the correct way to write new frame to session in freeswitch. For sound, I can hear original sound but with noise, I think it because I just replace the rest of the frame to 128, since I don't know how to just send the new frame.
For video, I just get core dumped after few times execute decryption and frame replacing.
I am beginner in C, also maybe someone who understand FreeSwitch could help me. Thank you so much.

Do not tag C++ for C questions.
